# Getting a null value while trying to parse a byte array to an xml Document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm working on extracting values from an xml document stored as a byte array in the db. I'm trying to pass the value of that byte array after unzipping. I don't have a lot of experience working with xmls so it's entirely possible I'm doing it all wrong. Here's my code so far:

```
public static Document getXmlFromByteArray(byte[] array) throws IOException {
try {
        String xmlString = new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        LOGGER.info(xmlString);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
        Document document = builder.parse(is);
        LOGGER.info(document.toString());
        return document;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

Here I'm using javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder as the parser and org.w3c.dom.Document for the document

Now, I've ensured that both the byte array and the string are being set correctly, here's an example of the log I'm getting from this

INFO: [the class] `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Signatures>dummy signature</Signatures>`
INFO: [the class] [#document: null]

I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. If I can't figure out how to use the

I've initially tried doing it like this:

```
public static Document getXmlFromByteArray(byte[] array) throws IOException {
    try {
        LOGGER.info(Arrays.toString(array));
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
        InputSource input = new InputSource(bis);
        Document document = builder.parse(input);
        LOGGER.info(document.toString());
        if (document == null)
            throw new IOException("Error converting to xml!");
        return document;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

having since tried converting the byte array to a string manually and adding the
String xmlString = new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); line to make sure that the content of the document itself is valid, as well as manually fetching, unzipping and reading the xml from the database.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a matter of `document.toString()` returning null, even if `document` itself isn't null? If `document` is actually null, I'd expect your code to throw a `NullPointerException` rather than logging anything.

Comment: Wow, you're right! I never would have thought of that!

Doing this gives me both the version as well as the text from the XML:
    `LOGGER.info(document.getXmlVersion());
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Signatures");
    if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
        Element signaturesElement = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
 String signaturesText = signaturesElement.getTextContent();
 LOGGER.info("Signatures Text: " + signaturesText);
    }`

I think I know what's wrong now, thanks for the help :)!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like document.toString() didn't do what I expected. Despite the logged value being "[#document: null]" the document is actually being read here.

I've altered my code like so:

```
public static Document getXmlFromByteArray(byte[] array) throws IOException {
    try {
        String xmlString = new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        LOGGER.info(xmlString);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
        Document document = builder.parse(is);
        LOGGER.info(document.getXmlVersion());
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Signatures");
        if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
            Element signaturesElement = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
            String signaturesText = signaturesElement.getTextContent();
            LOGGER.info("Signatures Text: " + signaturesText);
        }    
        return document;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

I now get "1.0" and "Signatures Text: dummy signature" as expected.